# I'm having calculation issues with this code

Tags: python-3.x, performance, calculation

I have been having issues for the past 3 hours trying to figure out why the invalid input I am putting in is counting towards the GPA.

```
Data = True
while Data:
    totalScore = 0
    name = input("What is the Student's Name: ")
    quizCount = int(input(f"How many quizzes did {name} take: "))
    for x in range(quizCount):
        grade = float(input("Please enter grade for quiz " + str(x+1) + ": "))
        totalScore = totalScore + grade
        
        while grade > 100:
            print("Invalid Input")
            grade = float(input("Please enter a valid grade for quiz " + str(x+1) + ": ")
                
    average = totalScore/quizCount
    
    print("The average for", name, "is", average)

    value = input("Would you like to process another student? (Y/N): ")
    if value.lower() == "y":
        continue
    else:
        print ("Program Exited")
        break
```

Most of the code works, however I have no clue how to get the calculations correct. Because this is what I get after the inputs.

```
What is the Student's Name: t
How many quizzes did t take: 4
Please enter grade for quiz 1: 100
Please enter grade for quiz 2: 101
Invalid Input
Please enter a valid grade for quiz 2: 101
Invalid Input
Please enter a valid grade for quiz 2: 90
Please enter grade for quiz 3: 80
Please enter grade for quiz 4: 70
The average for t is 87.75
```

the correct answer is supposed to be 85.0... If anyone can help me on this that would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You are adding the grade to `totalScore` without first checking if it is valid

Answer (score 1):

Your probleme is in the for loop :

```py
for x in range(quizCount):
        grade = float(input("Please enter grade for quiz " + str(x+1) + ": "))
        totalScore = totalScore + grade
        
        while grade > 100:
            print("Invalid Input")
            grade = float(input("Please enter a valid grade for quiz " + str(x+1) + ": ")
```

In fact you are adding the first given grade to totalScore rather than adding the correct grade (<=100)
So you should rather do :

```py
for x in range(quizCount):
        grade = float(input("Please enter grade for quiz " + str(x+1) + ": "))
        
        while grade > 100:
            print("Invalid Input")
            grade = float(input("Please enter a valid grade for quiz " + str(x+1) + ": ")
        totalScore = totalScore + grade
```